# PHP Undefined Offset Within Class

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop, undefined-index

This one's been bugging me for the past day now. Here's the code:

```
public function getUserCredits()
{
    $dbl = new databaseManager();
    $dbl->connect_simp();
    $ret = $dbl->queryDB("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `USER_ID` = ".$this->userId);
    $this->userCredits = $ret['USER_CREDITS'];

    return $this->userCredits;
}
```

Now when I try to run this code, I get an `undefined offset` error. Nothing too strange about it when I first saw it, but now it's happening more and more and I can't figure out why.

I can use `var_dump();` and `var_export();` and it displays the contents of the returned array absolutely fine.

**EDIT:**

```
    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(50) {
    ["USER_ID"]=>
    string(10) "0000000001"
    [0]=>
    string(10) "0000000001"
    ["USER_USERNAME"]=>
    string(8) "SampleUsername"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "SampleUsername"
    ["USER_PASSWORD"]=>
    string(32) "5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99"
    [2]=>
    string(32) "5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99"
    ["USER_EMAIL"]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["USER_LEGION"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["USER_ENERGY"]=>
    string(4) "2812"
    [5]=>
    string(4) "2812"
    ["USER_MAX_ENERGY"]=>
    string(4) "2812"
    [6]=>
    string(4) "2812"
    ["USER_SHIELD"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [7]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["USER_MAX_SHIELD"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [8]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["USER_HULL"]=>
    string(2) "60"
    [9]=>
    string(2) "60"
    ["USER_MAX_HULL"]=>
    string(2) "60"
    [10]=>
    string(2) "60"
    ["USER_CREDITS"]=>
    string(19) "9223372036854775807"
```

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Comment: Can you add the output of `var_dump()` to the question?

Comment: please add var_dump result too.

Comment: This uses PDO within a custom class. I really do appreciate the advice, but this isn't what was asked. :|

Comment: Okay, added in the var_dump(); output. I've cut it short.

Comment: Going through PDO doesn't matter if you're building SQL statements with outside data.

Comment: @AndyLester It's all handled and is injection proof. Trust me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$ret[0]['USER_CREDITS']
```

instead of

```
$ret['USER_CREDITS']
```

Comment: That worked. I kinda feel stupid for not seeing it before. Thank you so much! Will mark as answer when it lets me. In the mean time, would you mind explaining why this works?

Comment: Ohh, I see it now. It's an array within an array.

Comment: don't worry, it happens sometimes.
this is because the result of sql query is an array of arrays.
the first array is all the columns in table the matched the condition, and the second array is the column's fields.

Comment: @JordanHughMcKimm You've got an error if user id not found in this case.

Comment: @AbuOmar This database class was written by a friend, and it's based on PDO. I'm used to looping through the result set with `mysql_fetch_array();` (hence why I wasn't expecting an array within an array). All this PDO/OOP stuff is quite new to me.

Thanks again. :) I better get back to finishing it off now. :P

Answer (score 0):

You gotta fetch a row first (I assume you extend `mysqli`).

```
$result = $dbl->queryDB("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `USER_ID` = ".$this->userId);
$row = $dbl->fetch_assoc($result) ;

$this->userCredits = $row['USER_CREDITS'];
```

Answer (score 0):

AS your `var_dump($ret)`, Try this to assign user credit otherwise if it is not set, assign `0` value.

```
if(isset($ret[0]['USER_CREDITS'])){
    $this->userCredits = $ret[0]['USER_CREDITS'];
}
else{
    $this->userCredits = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you should watch the result record. As you are getting the details in an array of your database record fetched and it is in array format with numeric keys. Use what @AbuOmar said.